# Data loader Error while Connecting to Sandbox error

Tags: data-loader

I am using Data Loader for Inserting Data . But when i am trying to login it is giving me error.

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you check if you are seeing this error for your personal developer account

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @ZenSeeker: Yes it is giving same error for my Personal org..

Comment: @manjit_singh: No

Comment: @ShantanuMahajan If you are not behind then make sure that the proxy host and port are blank in Dataloader settings. Also open you windows command prompt and try to ping salesforce.com `ping test.salesforce.com`

Answer (score 1):

Please append your security token to your password or whitelist your IP address. Also, try changing your instance server URL to https://**yourinstance**.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/34.0

Comment: I have tried this but it is not working

Comment: Please refer the below link and see if any of the resolution works for you:  >> https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005262&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried appending the Security Token with the Password while Login into the Data Loader. If not, Please use password = password + security token.

Its a problem with a proxy connection etc...

Please use the Endpoint URL : https://instance.salesforce.com
Thanks,
Vipul

Comment: No it is not working

Comment: What is the version of Data Loader you are using?

Comment: Please try using the previous data Loader version from the following link : http://www.cloudsuccess.com/resource-centre/apex-data-loader-archive/

Comment: Version is 34.0

Comment: Can you please try with the different data Loader version. If not, then try the following combination:   Instance URl: https://instance(ap1,na1).salesforce.com ; Use the Password : Password+securtiy Token;       If still issue persists then try to Lgin to your dev account from your home network because it might be the organization firewall or network issue.

Comment: @vipul, It is definitely a network issue, if it was a credential issue then the error message would be different like "Invalid username/ password or user locked out"